# How to store array with 1 identifier?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this JSON format from POSTMAN where it saves an array but for each index in the array it creates another `RecordID`. I want all data in the array to be in just 1 `RecordID.`

```
{
  "EmployeeID": "1",
  "RecordID": "0",
  "Schedule": [
    {
      "Days": "Sunday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "1",
      "TimeOut_AM": "1",
      "TimeIn_PM": "1",
      "TimeOut_PM": "1"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Monday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "sample string 2",
      "TimeOut_AM": "sample string 3",
      "TimeIn_PM": "sample string 4",
      "TimeOut_PM": "sample string 5"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Tuesday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "sample string 2",
      "TimeOut_AM": "sample string 3",
      "TimeIn_PM": "sample string 4",
      "TimeOut_PM": "sample string 5"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Wednesday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "sample string 2",
      "TimeOut_AM": "sample string 3",
      "TimeIn_PM": "sample string 4",
      "TimeOut_PM": "sample string 5"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Thursday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "sample string 2",
      "TimeOut_AM": "sample string 3",
      "TimeIn_PM": "sample string 4",
      "TimeOut_PM": "sample string 5"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Friday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "sample string 2",
      "TimeOut_AM": "sample string 3",
      "TimeIn_PM": "sample string 4",
      "TimeOut_PM": "sample string 5"
    },
    {
      "Days": "Saturday",
      "TimeIn_AM": "sample string 2",
      "TimeOut_AM": "sample string 3",
      "TimeIn_PM": "sample string 4",
      "TimeOut_PM": "sample string 5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my query:

```
@EmployeeID nvarchar(50), @RecordID INT, @Days nvarchar(50), @TimeIn_AM nvarchar(50), @TimeOut_AM nvarchar(50), @TimeIn_PM nvarchar(50),
                            @TimeOut_PM nvarchar(50) AS
                                IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from WorkScheduleDB)
                                BEGIN
                                      SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.WorkScheduleDB ON
                                            INSERT INTO WorkScheduleDB(EmployeeID, RecordID, Days, TimeIn_AM, TimeOut_AM, TimeIn_PM, TimeOut_PM)
                                                        Values(@EmployeeID, 1000, @Days, @TimeIn_AM, @TimeOut_AM, @TimeIn_PM, @TimeOut_PM)
                                END;
                               ELSE
                                BEGIN
                                      SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.WorkScheduleDB OFF
                                        UPDATE WorkScheduleDB Set EmployeeID = @EmployeeID, Days = @Days, TimeIn_AM = @TimeIn_AM, TimeOut_AM = @TimeOut_AM, TimeIn_PM = @TimeIn_PM, 
                                                                     TimeOut_PM = @TimeOut_PM WHERE RecordID = @RecordID
                                        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                                             INSERT INTO WorkScheduleDB(EmployeeID, Days, TimeIn_AM, TimeOut_AM, TimeIn_PM, TimeOut_PM)
                                                                 Values(@EmployeeID, @Days, @TimeIn_AM, @TimeOut_AM, @TimeIn_PM, @TimeOut_PM)
                                END;
                                   SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NewID;"
```

I don't know what is wrong with this but I guess its in the query or maybe its in how I handle the data when I saved it?
**Database Schema**
[image]
**i want to one `RecordID` for them all so that if i can update the data inside the array**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < employeeschedule.Schedule.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("WorkSchedule_Save", MyConnection);
                    mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.EmployeeID;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@RecordID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = employeeschedule.RecordID;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Days", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].Days;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeIn_AM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeIn_AM;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeOut_AM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeOut_AM;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeIn_PM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeIn_PM;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Add("TimeOut_PM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employeeschedule.Schedule[i].TimeOut_PM;
                    
                    MyConnection.Open();

                    SqlDataReader MyReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();

                    DataTable MyDataTable = new DataTable();
                    MyDataTable.Load(MyReader);
                    
                    if (MyDataTable.Rows.Count >= 1 && Convert.ToInt32(employeeschedule.RecordID) == 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow Record in MyDataTable.Rows)
                        { Result = Record["NewID"].ToString(); }
                    }
                    MyConnection.Close();

                }
```

**Save Method**

Comment: You should show us your table schema for WorkScheduleDB to get a better answer.  On a whim You probably need to comment out SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.WorkScheduleDB ON and SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.WorkScheduleDB OFF    Also Change   (Select * from WorkScheduleDB)  to  (Select * from WorkScheduleDB WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)    and comment out  SELECT @@IDENTITY.  Also Take out RecordID and the 1000 from the first insert statement.

Comment: @SqlSurfer there sir i updated the post and added the database schema

Comment: What has this got to do with C#?

Comment: EmployeeID looks like your "one record" id.   The Key looks like  EmployeeID+Days.   If you are doing a real time card record then you also need year and month and day - or year and week number.  Right now the way you are asking the question and the actual data and the table schema do not agree with each other - based on what I am inferring from your question.

Comment: @Enigmativity my save method is in c# i included it because maybe it has to do with how i handle the data in my save method

Comment: @sim - Perhaps you should show the code?

Comment: @SqlSurfer im just making thier weekly sched and also why i wanted that to have only one RecordID so that i can Change the value of the array without changing the ```RecordID```.

Comment: @Enigmativity i updated my question sir.. iincluded the method now

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is create a unique ID that will refer to your entire request. If you have that ID, you can use it as a value for RecordID that will allow you to reference all of the rows that were added to the table you're showing us during a particular request. The typical way to do this is to create a separate table, typically called a parent table, and insert just one row in that table during a request. You can define that table with an `IDENTITY` column, and read the value for your RecordID value from the value of `@@IDENTITY` after you insert the parent record (note: `@@IDENTITY` is deprecated, please see the docs on `SCOPE_IDENTITY`). I'd recommend taking the IDENTITY constraint off of the table you're showing us (this would be the 'child' table), because it's not being used in a consistent way.